# Choosing a cloud database for information on a spreadsheet

Tags: sql, database, google-cloud-platform, data-migration

I'd like to migrate a growing google spreadsheet to a cloud database service, such as Google Cloud, because I want to be able to run queries and data analysis. I'm entirely new to database structures, so It's been hard to even know where to look or how to ask the right questions. Let me describe what I'm looking for and hopefully my questions is clear enough for someone to help.

-I have a google spreadsheet of users and how we interact with them. I want to be able to run analysis on our users via software like Python or R. Right now, it's pretty small (like 50 people and 1000 interactions).

-I want to be able to see all the queries run on this database and restrict some information to protect privacy if necessary (some columns I wouldn't want some analysts to be able to access).

-the way we input information is manually (like if a new user signs up i just put that in the spreadsheet) and we automatically log interactions through a zapier flow.

Would google cloud be good for something like this, or should I try another service?

Thanks and please let me know if I can do anything to make the question more clear.

Comment: I'm sure this question will get put on hold as "opnion based" but before that happens yes you should look at cloud based databases. Personal opinion is I would use Azure SQL, others will be passionate about the equivalent products from AWS and Google. Look specifically for their database products, as "Google Cloud", "Azure" or "AWS" encompass hundreds of services.

Comment: Everything you described can be done in simple Python. However, Google BiqQuery has good integration with Sheets.

Comment: What issue do you have with the current platform? Are you worried that your current analysis won't scale? How do you do your analysis currently? What analytics platforms are you happy using (R, Python, SQL?). You say 'if a new user signs up' - how does this sign up currently occur? Is it a paper based signup? You basically want advice on a custom system build here involving data entry, R (or Python), relational (SQL), row/column level security. And you want to build it in the cloud.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. Currently I use Google spreadsheets and don't have a way to do analysis without downloading it on a local machine. I'm figuring out the best way the turn it in to a database but it's pretty small so far so didn't know what to do yet